# Animation distance for wow.js/animate.css?

Tags: animation, animate.css, wow.js

Is there a way to reduce the distance the animating div travels from? For `fadeInUp`, it's currently coming from off the screen. I only want it to travel from 30px down. I thought it would be `data-wow-offset` but changing its values is not changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the css animation in animate.css. 
[Check this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618233/animate-css-animating-distance?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use overflow hidden to avoid this